# Text within an equation

Tags: equations

I am trying to achieve the equation shown in the figure attached below[image: equation required]

I am not getting the desired result in terms of the alignment of the text between equations and the main text.

I have tried `text` mode with `split` in `equation` option, but the alignment of text is not correct (First equation in the MWE below). Next (second equation in the MWE)I tried with `split` `intertext` and `gather`, which aligns the text, but it also aligns the equations to the left with the main text and the right brace and equation number is also screwed up.

[image: attempted equation]

Is there any way to achieve this?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{split}
\text{with respect to point $B$}\\
aP_{1}-2aN_{c}+3aP_{2} & = 0\\
\text{with respect to point $C$}\\
2aN_{B}-aP_{1}+aP_{2} &=0\\
\end{split}
\right\}
\label{label-of-equation}
\end{equation}

\begin{gather}
\left.
\begin{split}
\intertext{with respect to point $B$}
aP_{1}-2aN_{c}+3aP_{2} & = 0\\
\intertext{with respect to point $C$}
2aN_{B}-aP_{1}+aP_{2} &=0\\
\end{split}
\right\}
\label{label-of-equation}
\end{gather}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `empheq` package (which loads `mathtools` and `amsmath`) can help reproduce the O.P.'s image:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{empheq}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]%
\begin{empheq}[right =\mathrlap{\enspace\empheqrbrace}]{align}%
\shortintertext{with respect to point $B$: }
&aP_{1}-2aN_{c}+3aP_{2} = 0 \notag\\[-1ex]\\[-1ex]
\shortintertext{with respect to point $C$: }
&2aN_{B}-aP_{1}+aP_{2}=0\notag
\label{label-of-equation}
\end{empheq}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to move the equation to the left margin is to
insert the command 
`\displayindent=-103pt`between `\begin{equation}` and   `\left.` (Maybe you will 
have to  play with the exact number.)
Disadvantage: the number of the equation will also move to the left.

Comment: The `-103pt` seems arbitrary, and probably has to change whenever the text block/page dimensions change.